# Python Matplotlib Slider is drawn but doesnt move or update

Tags: python, matplotlib, slider

I am trying to draw a scatter plot with a point that moves based on a parameter adjusted by a slider. I need the parameter to be the position in a list of the coordinates. I have it so the scatter plot gets drawn and I can manually move the point by change the position, but when I try to implement the slider it is displayed, but can not be drug to update the plot. Any help would be great. What I have so far is below. Thanks.

```
%pylab
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import animation

def on_change(val):
   p=int(val)/1

def chart():
    x=[0,0.5,1]
    y=[0,0.5,1]
    z=[0,0.5,1]
    p=0
    fig = pyplot.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    ax.plot([0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],[0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1],[0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0],c='black',zorder=10)
    ax.scatter(x[p],y[p],z[p],zorder=0)
    ax.set_xlabel('Width')
    ax.set_ylabel('Depth')
    ax.set_zlabel('Height')
    slider_ax = plt.axes([0.15, 0.05, 0.7, 0.02])
    slider = Slider(slider_ax, "min", 0, 2, valinit=1, color='blue')
    pyplot.show()

chart()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to keep a reference to the `Slider` object around or it (and it's call backs) get garbage collected.  See long discussion at https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3105.

The documentation on this has been clarified for 1.4.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. Now my issue is that is that when the slider updates the plot, it adds a point to the plot (total of 3 points showing at end) and what I need it to do is have it clear the plot and replot the point at a new position (1 point appears to move from point A to point B. The updated code is above.

Comment: If this solved the problem you asked, then please accept this answer and open a new question with your new problem.  Answering moving-target questions is very annoying.