# want matplotlib slider plot called from class

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have working code to create a slider plot with my data, but it would be much cleaner and more convenient if I could call the plot from a different script rather than having it at the end of my code. I attempted to adjust what I already had (very much based on the matplotlib slider demo) to be callable as a class, but now the slider doesn't respond when I click on the figure. Do I need something like `mpl_connect`? Here's my code

```
class slider_plot():
    def __init__(self,predictions,Y_data):
        self.predictions=predictions
        self.Y_data=Y_data


    def update(self,val):
        self.ax.collections.clear()
        i = int(data_number.val)
        self.l1.set_ydata(self.predictions[data_point_number])
        self.l2.set_ydata(self.Y_data[data_point_number])
        length=len(self.predictions[data_point_number])



    def plot(self):
        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots()       
        plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.1)
        i=0
        self.l1,=plt.plot(self.predictions[i],label="Prediction",color=colors[1])
        sns.despine(left=True,bottom=True,right=True)
        self.ax.set_xticks([])

        self.l2,=plt.plot(self.Y_data[i],label="Measured",color='darkgray')

        plt.legend(loc='best', prop={'size': 16})
        plt.title("Prediction vs. Measured",fontsize=16)
        self.ax.set_ylim(np.min(1.1*self.Y_data),np.max(1.1*self.Y_data))
        axcolor = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'
        axdata = plt.axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03], facecolor=axcolor)

        data_number = Slider(axdata, 'Sample Number', 0, len(predict)-1, valinit=0, valstep=1)


        data_number.on_changed(self.update)
```

Comment: You need to keep a reference to the slider, e.g. `self.variable_name = Slider(...)`, else it will be garbage collected.

Comment: Of course! Such a silly mistake. Now The plot is updating, but only once. When I click on the Slider bar a second time nothing happens. I'll double check everything myself first though. Thanks!

Comment: Everything's working now. I was just missing another self declaration. If you repost your comment as an answer I'd gladly declare it the answer

Comment: I closed this as duplicate of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24899159/python-matplotlib-slider-is-drawn-but-doesnt-move-or-update) if you don't mind.

Comment: Not in the least